# Regarding navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios4

Here in my application i created a leftbarbuttonitem programatically in viewWillAppear methos, i have two click twice to work this, my code is as follows.

```
    Code for creating UIBarButtonItem(left bar button)

    goingBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
goingBackButton.title = @"Back";
goingBackButton.target = self;
goingBackButton.action = @selector(backAction);
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = goingBackButton;
[goingBackButton release];


    Action code

    - (IBAction) backAction {

NSLog(@"Inside the backAction of uploadViewController");
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Inside the backAction1 of uploadViewController");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:@selector(back)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bar;
[bar release];  

-(void)back  
{  
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I tried with this code also, but there is no change in functionality. Please if there is any way let me know.

Comment: is there is any network action going on the viewcontroller which is pushed

Comment: That's why it take some time to push the controller.One thing you can do push the controller without hanging is,in your viedidload or viewwillappear method add the line of code given here   [self performSelector:@selector(streamvideo) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5]; and then inside that method put your video streaming code .Hope it helps you.....